# Watson Assistant CURL API: How to handle the Responds with OPTIONS?

Tags: php, curl, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I'm trying out IBM Watson Assistant. Ultimate goal is to integrate it with my custom PHP backend, via it's [Watson Assistant's cURL API Endpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JLLb.png) *(because there's no complete PHP SDK yet)*.

When I setup a Dialog with the **OPTIONS** (other than, **TEXT**) as the Respond, the OPTIONS are perfectly working inside it's own "***Try it out***" Chat Window. But when I query it through the cURL API as usual, everything else is working except for that Dialogs with OPTIONS.

Here's the working example inside ***Try it out*** Window:

[image]

But then, here's the return from cURL API (for the same question asked):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [intents] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [intent] => SOexchangenetworks
                    [confidence] => 1
                )

        )

    [entities] => Array
        (
        )

    [input] => stdClass Object
        (
            [text] => Which Stack Exchange Network should I go to look for an answer?
        )

    [output] => stdClass Object
        (
            [text] => Array
                (
                )

            [nodes_visited] => Array
                (
                    [0] => node_1_1531885028865
                )

            [log_messages] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [context] => stdClass Object
        (
            [conversation_id] => 77ec8fc6-fb6a-4890-92b4-c58cdbc85ba3
            [system] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [dialog_stack] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [dialog_node] => root
                                )

                        )

                    [dialog_turn_counter] => 1
                    [dialog_request_counter] => 1
                    [branch_exited] => 1
                    [branch_exited_reason] => completed
                )

        )

)
```

### Problem Highlight:

You can see that `[output][text]` section is totally blank, when the Dialog Respond contains OPTIONS.

Note: Normally, the `[output][text]` section contains the reply from Watson, if the Respond type is `Text`. I've been keep using this cURL API for a while.

How do I solve this please?

Comment: What is your curl command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [Watson Assistant release](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/release-notes.html#release-notes) notes so called "rich responses" were added July 2018. The [current API version](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/curl.html?curl#introduction) is `2018-07-10`. In your curl command you are using the API version `2018-02-16`. Try the curl command again, but we the current API version.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much. That works! Should it then be safe NOT to define the version number please (aka) better ignore that parameter?

Comment: The version is a required parameter for all API calls. The reason is that sometimes there are breaking changes, i.e., semantics might change. Thus, the version is required to define your expected result. Please mark as answered.